# How to make my jquery code simple?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the li text of the ul,so I write my code like these:

```
  $("#ul li:first").text("0");
  $("#ul li:eq(1)").text("1");
  $("#ul li:last").text("2");
```

I think that I can get the jquery object firstly,so that I do not need to visit the ul three times,so I write like these,but it seems failed.

```
  var $ul=$("#ul");
  $ul("li:first").text("0");
  $ul("li:eq(1)").text("1");
  $ul("li:last").text("2");
```

I change my codes,but it still wrong.

```
  var $ulli=$("#ul li");
  $ulli(":first").text("0");
  $ulli(":eq(1)").text("1");
  $ulli(":last").text("2");
```

Comment: `$ul.children("li:first")` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the method of the jquery.

```
$ul.find("li:first")
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is great when you have to process objects in batch mode like here. So a natural jQuery way to do what you want could be :

```
$("#ul li").text(function(i) { return i; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to use jQuery object as a function, but you need a method of jQuery object.
Try to do this:
`$ul.find(<selector>)`

Answer (score 0):

You can choose all li's in a ul using the > selector `$("#testing > li")`.
Use the each() function to iterate through all li's

```
var i = 0;
$("ul > li").each(function (index, value) { 
 $(this).text(i++) 
});
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

the shortest way is:

```
$("ul li").each(function(index){$(this).text(index)});
```